# Calling API with POST method via Zombie.js browser

Tags: node.js, testing, post, browser, zombie.js

I'm working on testing my node.js code with Zombie.js. I have the following api, which is in POST method:

```
/api/names
```

and following code in my test/person.js file:

```
it('Test Retreiving Names Via Browser', function(done){
    this.timeout(10000);
    var url = host + "/api/names";
    var browser = new zombie.Browser();
    browser.visit(url, function(err, _browser, status){
       if(browser.error)
       {
           console.log("Invalid url!!! " + url);
       }
       else
       {
           console.log("Valid url!!!" + ". Status " + status);
       }
       done();
    });
});
```

Now, when I execute the command **mocha** from my terminal, it gets into **browser.error** condition. However, if I set my API to get method, it works as expected and gets into **Valid Url** (else part). I guess this is because of having my API in post method.

PS: I don't have any Form created to execute the queries on button click as I'm developing a back-end for mobile.

Any help on how to execute APIs with POST method would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zombie is more for interacting with actual webpages, and in the case of post requests actual forms.

For your test use the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module and manually craft the post request yourself

```
var request = require('request')
var should = require('should')
describe('URL names', function () {
  it('Should give error on invalid url', function(done) {
    // assume the following url is invalid
    var url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/names'
    var opts = {
      url: url,
      method: 'post'
    }
    request(opts, function (err, res, body) {
      // you will need to customize the assertions below based on your server

      // if server returns an actual error
      should.exist(err)
      // maybe you want to check the status code
      res.statusCode.should.eql(404, 'wrong status code returned from server')
      done()
    })
  })

  it('Should not give error on valid url', function(done) {
    // assume the following url is valid
    var url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/foo'
    var opts = {
      url: url,
      method: 'post'
    }
    request(opts, function (err, res, body) {
      // you will need to customize the assertions below based on your server

      // if server returns an actual error
      should.not.exist(err)
      // maybe you want to check the status code
      res.statusCode.should.eql(200, 'wrong status code returned from server')
      done()
    })
  })
})
```

For the example code above you will need the `request` and `should` modules

```
npm install --save-dev request should
```